# In C# what is the point of defining a delegate when we you can use Action<>, Func<>

Tags: c#

In C#, what is the point of defining a delegate when you can use `Action<>`, `Func<>`. Also, what is the point of doing `new Delegate(method)` to pass a method as a parameter when you can pass in the method directly as an argument? I saw this being done with WaitCallback delegate with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem().

```
class Program
{
    public delegate void SampleDelegate(string str);

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var classA = new A();
            classA.DoSomething(new SampleDelegate(MethodA), "hello world");
           //Why not just classA.DoSomething(MethodA, "hello world");
        }

        private static void MethodA(string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
}

class A
{
    public void DoSomething(SampleDelegate sampleDelegate, string str) //Why not DoSomething(Action<string> sampleDelegate, string str)
    {
         sampleDelegate(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly two reasons: 1) many of those delegates have been defined before generics and `Action<>` + `Func<>` were available 2) Clarity: `Func<string, string, string, bool>` does not tell you much about what those parameters are.

Comment: "I saw this being done with WaitCallback delegate with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()"  Did you look at decompiled code? Decompilers tend to emit code like that.

Comment: If you want to pass a parameter by ref for example.

Comment: There aren't built-in delegates for *every* possible signature. `Action` and `Func` doesn't let you handle `ref`, `out`, or `params` parameters, for example.

Comment: The `new DelegateType(method)` construct is still often written by developers who don't know any better, or who have old editions of Visual Studio autogenerate this for them. The short answer to many "why don't we just use this convenient shorthand" questions is "because the convenient shorthand didn't exist for a long time, and the clunkiness of the full form is why it was introduced in the first place". Delegates have been part of C# all the way back since version 1.0, and back then the language looked a lot more like old school Java did. Things have come quite a long way since then.